# Adding/Modifying TODO keywords

Tags: org-mode

I just installed Emacs 25.1 for windows.
I want to modify the TODO keyword list, and I use this code:

```
 (setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO"
      "MAYBE"
      "NEXT"
      "STARTED"
      "WAITING"
      "DELEGATED"
      "|"
      "DONE"
      "DEFERRED"
      "CANCELLED")))
```

However, the TODO items keep cycling between the standard keywords.
Strangely enough, if I check the variable 'org-todo-keywords from within the customization buffer, I do see all the keywords I've defined.

Any hints on why the do not appear when cycling?

Comment: Have you reverted (/re-opened) the buffer since setting `org-todo-keywords`?

Comment: I have put the code above directly in the buffer I'm visiting and evaluated the region `M-: eval-region`.

Comment: Try saving and re-opening the file.

Comment: Yes - that worked!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Org-mode caches various things on load.  In this case `org-todo` relies on todo keyword state cached in `org-todo-kwd-alist` which is generated by `org-set-regexps-and-options` which is run when setting the mode to org-mode for the buffer.

If some org-mode customization doesn't seem to be taking effect it's usually a good idea to refresh things by reloading the buffer.  Either by saving, closing, and re-opening the file or reverting the file by `C-x C-v [return]` (`find-alternate-file`).

I would personally consider this a bug.  When emacs gets watchpoints (in v26.1 hopefully) minor caching issues like this should be easily addressed.

Comment: Any solution without reloading the buffer? I am using emacs 26.3 on a macbook pro.

Comment: Another way to apply these changes: `(revert-buffer :ignore-auto :noconfirm)`

Answer (score 17):

As others have mentioned, `org-mode`  caches things like the todo keywords when it starts.  You can close and reopen the files, but `org-mode` provides a function `org-mode-restart` you can use.  If some setting doesn't seem to be taking effect, try `M-x org-mode-restart`.